# Abstract with heading to the left: abstract package broken?

Tags: abstract

I try to get the abstract heading set to the left and the package `abstract` seems to provide this functionality. But the pdf contains the characters "centerflushleft" and the abstract title is centered. Is the package broken? I use texlive 2012. Is there another way to achieve the desired result?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}

\absnamepos{flushleft}
%\abstitlestyle{\abstractname}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}



\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This paper provides an overview of the most important grammatical properties of German. A large part
of the paper is concerend with the basic clause types of German. I start with the Topological Fields Model,
which is very useful as a descriptive tool, but -- as will be shown -- not sufficient for a thorough
account of German clausal structure. I therefore explain additional theoretical assumptions that
were made in order to assign structure to the observable linear sequences. After a sketch of an
analysis of the basic sentence patterns, I
give an account of passive, case assignment, and subject-verb agreement.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}`

Comment: The package doesn't respect the KOMA-script classes settings. Just as an example, the sans-serif font used by default for the titles of the sectional units is lost in the abstract just by loading the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\absnamepos` command is defined in `abstract.sty` by

```
\newcommand{\absnamepos}{center}
```

so you should use `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This paper provides an overview of the most important grammatical properties of German. A large part
of the paper is concerend with the basic clause types of German. I start with the Topological Fields Model,
which is very useful as a descriptive tool, but -- as will be shown -- not sufficient for a thorough
account of German clausal structure. I therefore explain additional theoretical assumptions that
were made in order to assign structure to the observable linear sequences. After a sketch of an
analysis of the basic sentence patterns, I
give an account of passive, case assignment, and subject-verb agreement.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry for my silly question ...

Comment: @StefanMüller The user documentation is not really clear about this.

Answer (score 4):

The `abstract` package is not fully compatible with the KOMA classes; for example, just by loading it, the sans-serif font used by default for the sectional units is lost for the abstract.

Instead of using this package, to keep consistency with the class settings, you can redefine the way `abstract` is defined in `scrartcl.cls`:

```
\documentclass[abstract,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@titlepage
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \if@abstrt
      \begin{flushleft}
        \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{flushleft}
    \fi
  \else
    \if@twocolumn\if@abstrt
        \addsec*{\abstractname}
      \fi
      \quotation
    \else
      \if@abstrt
        \par\small\noindent%
          {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname\par\vspace{.5em}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}{%
  \if@titlepage
    \par\vfil\null\endtitlepage
  \else
    \if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This paper provides an overview of the most important grammatical properties of German. A large part
of the paper is concerend with the basic clause types of German. I start with the Topological Fields Model,
which is very useful as a descriptive tool, but -- as will be shown -- not sufficient for a thorough
account of German clausal structure. I therefore explain additional theoretical assumptions that
were made in order to assign structure to the observable linear sequences. After a sketch of an
analysis of the basic sentence patterns, I
give an account of passive, case assignment, and subject-verb agreement.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! De Gruyter wants the abstract in italics. Where would I integrate this into the above code?

Comment: @StefanMüller You can use `\itshape` right after the `\noindent` command inside abstract. This will change the font of the abstract body. Do you also need to change the font of the title "Abstract"?